# Dictionary from Automate the boring stuff with Python

Tags: python-3.x

This program is from "Automate the boring stuff with python". I am not able to understand, what tells the program to take "name" as **Key** and "bday" as **Value**

```
birthdays = {'Alice': 'Apr 1', 'Bob': 'Dec 12', 'Carol': 'Mar 4'}

   while True:
       print('Enter a name: (blank to quit)')
       name = input()
       if name == '':
           break

    if name in birthdays:
         print(birthdays[name] + ' is the birthday of ' + name)
       else:
           print('I do not have birthday information for ' + name)
           print('What is their birthday?')
           bday = input()
           birthdays[name] = bday
           print('Birthday database updated.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we can directly add key , value to dictionary

For reference:

```
d = {}
print(d)
d['Name']='1st April';
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{}
{'Name': '1st April'}
```

Here, 'Name' is **key** and '1st April' is **value**.

Python recognize key from inside bracket[] and value as assigned like d[**key**] = **value**

To look in to detail in dictionary refer : [Python Dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You may read the dict documentation : [Python dict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)

In the line `a_dictionnary[xxx] = yyy`

`xxx` is named **key** and `yyy` is named **value**.

Answer (score 2):

*line 9* - `if name in birthdays:`

When a check is done on a list with the `in` keyword without adding any method to the dictionary, it automatically checks its keys.

For example, if `name` in `birthdays` is the same as an entry in `birthdays.keys()`, `bday` is set to user input.

When it is used like `birthdays[name]=bday`, it's like adding a key-value pair to the dictionary `birthdays`.